# Restore from backup with new Apple ID

Tags: ipad, backup, apple-id, restore

I have an old iPad 3rd Generation (Retina Display). I am planning on buying the new iPad Pro 10.5. I am a little confused with backup and restore.

The old iPad has `Kanini.Mom@gmail.com` as the Apple ID (as it was my mom's iPad).

The new iPad is for my dad and so the Apple ID is going to be `Dad@gmail.com`

What I would like to do is:

1. Retain Photos
2. Retain Books from iBooks (These are PDF's not something which was purchased from iBook Store)

I do not need the games and other apps that was in the old iPad to be transferred in the new iPad.

I do want it use my new email address for everything (Apple ID, FaceTime, iMessages) etc.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: The items you reference are tied to the user's Apple ID so it's not possible to do what you want.  Once you change the Apple ID you become a different user to the iPad.  What about simply changing the email address associated with the one Apple ID from your mom's to your dad's, would that work for you?

Comment: @fsb Sorry, I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: @fsb Can you please explain what you mean by change the email address associated with one Apple ID to another?

Comment: The data associated with your mom's Apple ID can only be access by someone using that same Apple ID.  If your dad has a different Apple ID, your mom's backups will not work with your dad's Apple ID.  You can change the email address associated with an Apple ID.  Will it do what you want if you simply change your mom's Apple ID email address to be your dad's email address?

Comment: @fsb Thanks! No, that wouldn't work for us. That is alright, we installed Google Photos and copied the photos across to Dad's Gmail and set Dad's iPad as a new device.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to find a solution.  It would be great if you could add that as an answer to your question and then accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *fsb* mentions, the photos are all tied with the Apple Id which is associated with the iPad. So, here is what we did

1. Connect iPad to PC / Mac
2. Copy all of the photos from iPad to PC / Mac
3. Upload photos to Google Photos associated with Dad's gmail
4. In the new iPad, sign in with Dad's email address (this can be the same gmail account as above or a new account).
5. Download the Google Photos app and sign into it with the gmail mentioned in step 3.